# How to define a function with 3 variables in GNUPLOT

Tags: variables, vector, 3d, gnuplot

I am new to GNUPLOT. I am trying to plot 3d vector fields. However I am having trouble defining a function of three variables f(x,y,z). Can anyone show me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Defining your own functions in gnuplot is pretty intuitive. According to the [gnuplot documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node60.html) the syntax is as follows

```
<func-name>( <dummy1> {,<dummy2>} ... {,<dummy5>} ) = <expression>
```

Examples:

```
 w = 2
 q = floor(tan(pi/2 - 0.1))
 f(x) = sin(w*x)
 sinc(x) = sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)
 delta(t) = (t == 0)
 ramp(t) = (t > 0) ? t : 0
 min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
 comb(n,k) = n!/(k!*(n-k)!)
 len3d(x,y,z) = sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)
 plot f(x) = sin(x*a), a = 0.2, f(x), a = 0.4, f(x)
```

- There is also a large set of [built-in mathematical functions](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node53.html) which you can use (in the definition of your own function).
- For piecewise defined functions you can use the fact that undefined values are ignored. Therefore, the function
  `y(x) = x < 0 ? 1/0 : x`
  is only defined for positive arguments.
- Powers are defined by `**`. Hence `f(x)=x*x` is identical to `f(x)=x**2`

If you have still problems in defining your own function, please feel free to ask. (Shouldn't a 3d-function only depend on `x` and `y`, i.e., `f(x,y)=...`?)

For examples of 3d plots, also see the [gnuplot demo site](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/hidden.html).